# How to change data-validate attribute of a field?

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery, form-validation

I have a following form

```
<form name="addForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="someurl" data-hasrequired="<?php echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
<select id="sel1" name="sel1" data-validate="true"></select>
<select id="sel2" name="sel2" data-validate="false"></select>
<button name="btn-ex" type="submit" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                                    <span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span>
                                </button>
</form>
```

I'm filling `#sel1` and `#sel2` using jquery with default selected to "blank".
Now when user changes #sel1 then I want `#sel2` to be required.
When I change `#sel2` attribute data-validate="true" and reload the page, it works, but I need that on change of `#sel1`.
I wrote following jQuery on change method.

```
$('#sel1').change(function(){
                if($(this).val!="" || $(this).val!="0.00"){
                    jQuery('#sel2').attr('data-validate','{required:true}');
                }
                else{
                    jQuery('#sel2').attr('data-validate','{required:false}');
                }
            });
```

The jQuery code works and changes the attribute value of `#sel2` but on click of Submit it doesn't validate.

Answer (score 0):

you should create variable:

> var dataForm = $('#form-validate');

```
window.FormValidate = dataForm.mage('validation');
$('#sel1').change(function(){
                if($(this).val!="" || $(this).val!="0.00"){
                    jQuery('#sel2').attr('data-validate','{required:true}');
                     window.FormValidate;
                }
                else{
                    jQuery('#sel2').attr('data-validate','{required:false}');
                    window.FormValidate;
                }
            });
```